# What is the largest distance for which the influence of the electric field of a single electron was measured?

Tags: electrons, electric-fields, atoms

I suppose that Rydberg atoms are the best way to find by experiments the largest distance of influence of the electric field of a single electron in a electric dipole. Furthermore how the electrical positive charged nucleus influence this distance? Are there experiments with helium molecules or atoms with only one Rydberg electron?

Update: According to the below fig. from Wikipedia, how there can be a finite ionisation level if the electric field of an electron is infinite? It has to be an empiric value?

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom]

Comment: The electric field of an electron is not infinite.  It can, in theory, extend to an infinite spatial distance if given enough time but its magnitude is not infinite.

Comment: @honeste_vivere [Here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/electricity-magnetism-is-an-electric-field-infinite) it is pointed out, that the electron energy from its electric field is finite, but the field is infinite.

Comment: My point is to say that the field magnitude cannot be infinite, as that would imply an infinite amount of energy.  The field can extend, in theory, over an infinite spatial distance if given an infinite time to propagate.