# What is the practical Length of photons, in vacuum for example

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, photons

From practical point of view we know the width of photons is proportional to wavelengths (experiments for light going through tiny holes: it starts with a specific size of the holes, etc). And nobody talks in high-math language for this, though yes, like rings of smoke we understand that when hole size is small enough "effects" depend of materials, objects, etc, because of field density, probability, etc.  What about the photon length, what is it from the similar experiments (were there such experiments)? You are the only person I saw who mentioned that length of photon might be constant.  Any Ideas on what it is?
Thank you!
P.S. As to comments in quant-equations, packets, etc. - I see it as lack of our math, not as an explanation.

Comment: " photon length, what is it from the similar experiments (were there such experiments)? You are the only person I saw who mentioned that length of photon might be constant. Any Ideas on what it is?
Thank you! P.S. As to comments in quant-equations, packets, etc. - I see it as lack of our math, not as an explanation." What do you mean by "photon length" ?

Comment: That is excellent: “From practical point of view we know the width of photons is proportional to wavelengths (experiments for light going through tiny holes: it starts with a specific size of the holes, etc)” but you want get confirmed: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220294/how-the-infinite-electric-field-of-an-electron-goes-through-a-slit